# Upgrading to Rails 4.1 from 4.0, now all tests are broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I upgraded my rails version to 4.1.1 from 4.0.4. 
Whenever I run rake test I get every test having this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "roles_users" does not exist
LINE 1: DELETE FROM "roles_users"
                    ^
: DELETE FROM "roles_users"
```

My user controller has and belongs to many roles

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :some_names,
  class_name: "Role",
  join_table: "some_names_users"
```

So it should not be looking for roles_users as a table, but seems to be in the fixtures for my tests.

I am using minitest 5.3.4. I am not using the gem turn.

Comment: did you run your migrations, as this looks more like the tables are missing from the DB and not a rails problem

Comment: It is the issue described by Dylan below, there's an issue with join_table option not being recognized in 4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Rails 4.1; it's already been fixed and I'd expect it to be part of the next release (4.1.2).

In the mean time, you might be able to use the 4-1-stable branch:

```
gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: '4-1-stable'
```

Github Issues:

- [Habtm join_table option is not recognized in fixtures](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14845)
- [Fix to use custom join table in habtm](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/14853)

Comment: Thanks.I wanted to pull this in for a fix on something from 4.0 but I guess I might wait a little longer.